# Given a 2D array - I want to create a new array using the values in the original array

Tags: c, pointers, 2d

I've written some code that takes the average of four cells from a 2D array. The conditions are that the columns and rows have to be an even value, if it isn't we ignore the last column/row.

I forgot to mention that this is part of a header file -  the 2D array is defined to be a array[x][y] in another file containing the main(). pastebin.com/LUXW5X6b

Given this, I believe the best approach would be to use pointers and malloc to access the heap and make changes. -> How would I go about accomplishing this?

```
uint8_t *half(const uint8_t array[],
              unsigned int cols,
              unsigned int rows) {
    // your code here
    int i, j;
    uint8_t new_rows = rows / 2;
    uint8_t new_cols = cols / 2;
    uint8_t new_array[new_rows][new_cols];
    if (new_rows % 2 != 0) {
        new_rows = new_rows - 1;
    }
    if (new_cols % 2 != 0) {
        new_cols = new_cols - 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < new_rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < new_cols; j++) {
            new_array[i][j] = average(array[2*i][2*j],
                                      array[2*i+1][2*j],
                                      array[2*i+1][2*j+1],
                                      array[2*i][2*j+1]);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: array[] is 1d   ..

Answer (score 1):

You must declare the argument array as a 2D array.  In C99, you can specify the dimensions using this syntax:

```
uint8_t *half(unsigned int cols, unsigned int rows,
              const uint8_t array[][cols]) {
}
```

There is another problem: you cannot return a pointer to the local array in automatic storage because this object becomes invalid as soon as the function returns.  A simple solution is to allocate the destination array in the caller function and pass to the function `half`:

```
int half(unsigned int cols, unsigned int rows,
         const uint8_t array[rows][cols],
         uint8_t output[rows / 2][cols / 2])
{
    unsigned int new_rows = rows / 2;
    unsigned int new_cols = cols / 2;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < new_rows; i++) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < new_cols; j++) {
            output[i][j] = average(array[2 * i    ][2 * j    ],
                                   array[2 * i + 1][2 * j    ],
                                   array[2 * i + 1][2 * j + 1],
                                   array[2 * i    ][2 * j + 1]);
        }    
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Note that arrays are passed as pointers to their first element (they *decay* into pointers), so the first dimensions in the prototype are simply ignored by the compiler, the above definition is equivalent to:

```
int half(unsigned int cols, unsigned int rows,
         const uint8_t array[][cols],
         uint8_t output[][cols / 2]) ...
```

Note also that your extra tests on `new_rows` and `new_cols` seem unnecessary as the integer division already rounds toward 0.  If the original array has odd dimensions, the reduced array is computed correctly, ignoring the last row and/or column.

Comment: Aye, thank you you made me realize I forgot to detail that the array is predefined in main(). This is my main -http://pastebin.com/LUXW5X6b